# accessing data attributes inside Google Charts draw() function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to get access to the data variables and addRow() outside of the drawVisualization() function. 
The issue I'm keep running into is if I have the data/addRow outside of the draw function I have errors in my console "Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined" or its "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"
Not sure this is feasible for google API. but please share your thoughts. check the code below

```
var data;
var chart;

function drawVisualization() {

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'data');
    data.addColumn('number', 'date');

    data.addRow([timeArr[i], valueArr[i]]);


    //console.log(valueArr);
    // use a DataView to 0-out all the values in the data set for the initial draw
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);


    // Create and draw the plot
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));


    var options = {
        title:" ",
        width: 960,
        height: 460,
        bar: { groupWidth: "40%" },
        legend: { position: "bottom" },
        animation: {"startup": true},
        curveType: 'function',
        lineWidth: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
        colors: ['red'],
        tooltip: {
            textStyle: {
              color: 'red',
              italic: true
            },
            showColorCode: true
        },
        animation: {
            startup: true,
            easing: 'inAndOut',
            //duration: 500
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: '',
            gridlines: {
              count: 8,
              color: '#999'
            }
            /*minValue: 1.3,
            maxValue: 1.4*/
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time Stamp'
        },
    };


    chart.draw(view, options);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** define `data` somewhere outside `drawVisualization`

```
var data;

function drawVisualization() {
  ...
```

---

**2)** remove `var` from `data` within `drawVisualization`

```
var data;

function drawVisualization() {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();  // <-- remove var declaration
  data.addColumn('string', 'data');
  data.addColumn('number', 'date');
```

---

**3)** and just be sure not to use `data` until after the `callback` in `google.charts.load` has fired...

**EDIT**

you can define the chart outside `drawVisualization` as well

once `drawVisualization` has been called for the first time,
you can access any method on either variable...

```
var data;
var chart;

function drawVisualization() {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();  // <-- remove var declaration
  data.addColumn('string', 'data');
  data.addColumn('number', 'date');

  chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
```

Comment: thanks Whitehat! yeah the variables in the draw function is accessible. But how about the methods? like data.addRow/addColumn and chart.draw. How can I borrow them?

Comment: see __EDIT__, once `drawVisualization` is called the first time, you should be able to access any method...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you trying to do here. I was wondering if I can call data.addRow method outside of drawVisualization() function. Which I did try, it gave me "Cannot read property 'addRow' of undefined" error

Comment: if `data` is defined outside of `drawVisualization` _and_ `drawVisualization` has been called at least once _and_ the `callback` from the `google.charts.load` has fired, then you shouldn't receive an error...

Comment: Please check the code I edited just now. I had data, and chart outside of draw function. And I also loaded the google.charts.load. but Im getting this error: "Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined".

Comment: I'm also trying to call "data.addColumn('string', 'data');" outside of the draw function. the chart respond with me a "Table has no columns."

Comment: I just figured out what I wanted. Thanks so much for the inspirations! really appreciate it